# "Otherwise" vs "In Case of" vs "Nonetheless" vs "Whenever"

Tags: conjunctions

[image: Question]

I'm stuck with the question given by my teacher, what do you think the best answer is? Since they're all doesn't suit to put as conjunctions in this sentence.

Comment: Small enterprises can afford this small robot. They would not be able to afford _other_, more expensive robots. Now can you work out the answer?

Comment: @Kate Are you, for your sins, a teacher? (And it really encourages me when members help out people posting questions not suitable for ELU in 'comments'; an 'answer' encourages further off-topic questions).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, I'm not a teacher; I just thought it was more useful to try to help the OP to find the answer than to either give or refuse it.

Comment: @Kate Nevertheless, a good teaching style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is **(A)**.

"otherwise", in this context, [means](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/otherwise):

> In circumstances different from those present or considered; or else.

Should we apply this definition to the sentence, it would come to mean that Baxter is affordable enough for enterprises that would not have enough money to purchase any packing/sorting robot **other than Baxter**.

As an example, let's say NPP Packaging Company only has $500 to spend on a new packaging robot, but every single robot of this kind on the market costs $800 or more. Therefore, NPP could not afford to purchase a packaging robot due to their limited budget.

A few days later, however, Baxter the sorting/packaging robot is released to the market and is priced at $450, which fits NPP's budget of $500. This allows the company to purchase a packaging robot, in contrast to a few days earlier when they could not afford any robots of this type.

Therefore, Baxter allows companies with budget constraints (such as NPP) to buy a robot that packs and sorts - the type of robot that used to be too expensive for them.